# Realvnc does not refresh Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I used REAL VNC to connect to a ubuntu machine. I can get it to connect however my remote window does not refresh at all and does not respond to mouse clicks.

After a bit of debugging I found that in the Display menu there was an effects section which had "None", "Basic" and something like "Enhanced" for smooth switching of desktops. I had to make it to None.

I upgraded to 11.05 of Ubuntu and I think it has rejigged this setting.

1. Can I please ask how to set this in Ubuntu? The Ubuntu 11 has annoyingly lost the menu so I need to know what I am looking/searching for and I dont quite remember the name of the option
2. Where/How can I see this menu in ubuntu 11? It is annoying to not know the list of options and having to type them.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, see the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)